# Generate following XML using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

Is it possible to obtain the following XML File using C#. The data is in SQL Server.

```
<Person HomeID="1">
  <Day ID="1">
    <String>I get up at 07:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at  07:30</String>
    <String>I go to office at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I come back from office at 17:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 19:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 21:30</String>
  </Day>
  <Day ID="2">
    <String>I get up at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 08:30</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 20:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 23:00</String>
  </Day>
</Person>
<Person HomeID="2">
  <Day ID="1">
    <String>I get up at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at  08:30</String>
    <String>I go to office at 09:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I come back from office at 18:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 20:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 22:00</String>
  </Day>
  <Day ID="2">
    <String>I get up at 09:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 10:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 19:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 22:30</String>
  </Day>
</Person>
```

---

I have two tables, TB1 and TB2.

Fields in TB1 are HomeID, DayID, TimeCode, timevalue.

```
    HomeID  DayID   TimeCode    timevalue
    1       1       1           07:00:00
    1       1       2           07:30:00
    1       1       3           08:00:00
    1       1       4           13:00:00
    1       1       5           17:00:00
    1       1       6           19:00:00
    1       1       7           21:30:00
    1       2       1           08:00:00
    1       2       2           08:30:00
    1       2       3           13:00:00
    1       2       4           20:00:00
    1       2       5           23:00:00
    2       1       1           08:00:00
    2       1       2           08:30:00
    2       1       3           09:00:00
    2       1       4           13:00:00
    2       1       5           18:00:00
    2       1       6           20:00:00
    2       1       7           22:00:00
    2       2       1           09:00:00
    2       2       2           10:00:00
    2       2       3           13:00:00
    2       2       4           19:00:00
    2       2       5           22:30:00
```

Fields in TB2 are DayType, StringCode, RndString.

```
    DayType     StringCode  RndString
    1       1           I get up at 
    1       2           I have breakfast at 
    1       3           I go to office at 
    1       4           I have lunch at 
    1       5           I come back from office at 
    1       6           I have dinner at 
    1       7           I sleep at 
    2       1           I get up at 
    2       2           I have breakfast at 
    2       3           I have lunch at 
    2       4           I have dinner at 
    2       5           I sleep at
```

**Note:** 
TB1.DayID=TB2.DayType and TB1.TimeCode=TB2.StringCode

The equivalent SQL Query to generate the desired XML Output is

```
select T1_1.HomeID as [@HomeID],
       (
       select T1_2.DayID as [@ID],
              (
              select T2.RndString+' '+left(T1_3.TimeValue, 5) as '*'
              from TB1 as T1_3
                inner join TB2 as T2
                  on T1_3.DayID = T2.DayType and
                     T1_3.TimeCode = T2.StringCode
              where T1_2.HomeID = T1_3.HomeID and
                    T1_2.DayID = T1_3.DayID
              order by T2.StringCode
              for xml path('String'), type
              )
       from TB1 as T1_2
       where T1_2.HomeID = T1_1.HomeID
       group by T1_2.DayID,
                T1_2.HomeID
       order by T1_2.DayID
       for xml path('Day'), type
       )
from TB1 as T1_1
group by T1_1.HomeID
order by T1_1.HomeID
for xml path('Person')
```

My trial at the solution.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace SQL
    {
        static class Program
        {
            // To generate XML File using C# from SQL Server Data

            // The main entry point for the application.
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                // Create a String to hold the database connection string.
                string sdwConnectionString = @"Data Source=IE1ADTBD5ZL1S\;Initial Catalog=RecommendEngine;Integrated Security=True";

                // Create a connection
                SqlConnection sdwDBConnection = new SqlConnection(sdwConnectionString);

                // Open the connection
                sdwDBConnection.Open();



                //Create a String to hold the query.
                string query = @"select T1_1.HomeID as [@HomeID],
                                                     (
                                                       select T1_2.DayID as [@ID],
                                                              (
                                                               select T2.RndString+' '+left(T1_3.TimeValue, 5) as '*'
                                                               from TB1 as T1_3
                                                                 inner join TB2 as T2
                                                                   on T1_3.DayID = T2.DayType and
                                                                      T1_3.TimeCode = T2.StringCode
                                                               where T1_2.HomeID = T1_3.HomeID and
                                                                     T1_2.DayID = T1_3.DayID
                                                               order by T2.StringCode
                                                               for xml path('String'), type
                                                              )
                                                       from TB1 as T1_2
                                                       where T1_2.HomeID = T1_1.HomeID
                                                       group by T1_2.DayID,
                                                                T1_2.HomeID
                                                       order by T1_2.DayID
                                                       for xml path('Day'), type
                                                      )
                                                     from TB1 as T1_1
                                                     group by T1_1.HomeID
                                                     order by T1_1.HomeID
                                                     for xml path('Person'), root('Persons')";

                //Create a SqlCommand object and pass the constructor the connection string and the query string.
                SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sdwDBConnection);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                new SqlDataAdapter(queryCommand).Fill(dt);
                dt.TableName = "TableName";
                dt.WriteXml(@"C:/SampleFile.xml");


                // Close the connection
                sdwDBConnection.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 for not showing any effort to try it yourself.

Comment: Hey I did try to solve the issue. But it didn't come out effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Schema:**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TB1 TABLE
(
        HomeID INT  
      , DayID INT
      , TimeCode INT 
      , timevalue CHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TB1 (HomeID, DayID, TimeCode, timevalue)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, '07:00:00'), (1, 1, 2, '07:30:00'),
    (1, 1, 3, '08:00:00'), (1, 1, 4, '13:00:00'),
    (1, 1, 5, '17:00:00'), (1, 1, 6, '19:00:00'),
    (1, 1, 7, '21:30:00'), (1, 2, 1, '08:00:00'),
    (1, 2, 2, '08:30:00'), (1, 2, 3, '13:00:00'),
    (1, 2, 4, '20:00:00'), (1, 2, 5, '23:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 1, '08:00:00'), (2, 1, 2, '08:30:00'),
    (2, 1, 3, '09:00:00'), (2, 1, 4, '13:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 5, '18:00:00'), (2, 1, 6, '20:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 7, '22:00:00'), (2, 2, 1, '09:00:00'),
    (2, 2, 2, '10:00:00'), (2, 2, 3, '13:00:00'),
    (2, 2, 4, '19:00:00'), (2, 2, 5, '22:30:00')

DECLARE @TB2 TABLE
(
        DayType INT
      , StringCode INT
      , RndString VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TB2 (DayType, StringCode, RndString)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'I get up at '),
    (1, 2, 'I have breakfast at '), 
    (1, 3, 'I go to office at '), 
    (1, 4, 'I have lunch at '),
    (1, 5, 'I come back from office at '), 
    (1, 6, 'I have dinner at '),
    (1, 7, 'I sleep at '),
    (2, 1, 'I get up at '),
    (2, 2, 'I have breakfast at '),
    (2, 3, 'I have lunch at '),
    (2, 4, 'I have dinner at '),
    (2, 5, 'I sleep at ')
```

**Example 1:**

```
SELECT 
      '@HomeID' = t.HomeID
    , (
            SELECT '@ID' = t2_.DayID
                , (
                    SELECT t4.RndString + LEFT(t3.TimeValue, 5)
                    FROM @TB1 t3
                    JOIN @TB2 t4 ON t3.DayID = t4.DayType AND t3.TimeCode = t4.StringCode
                    WHERE t2_.DayID = t3.DayID
                        AND t.HomeID = t3.HomeID 
                    FOR XML PATH ('String'), TYPE
                )
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT t2.DayID
                FROM @TB1 t2
                WHERE t.HomeID = t2.HomeID
            ) t2_
            FOR XML PATH ('Day'), TYPE
        )
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.HomeID
    FROM @TB1 T1
) t
FOR XML PATH ('Person'), TYPE
```

**Example 2:**

```
SELECT 
        Person.HomeID
      , ID = [Day].DayID
      , String.String
FROM @TB1 Person
JOIN (
    SELECT T1.HomeID, T1.DayID
    FROM @TB1 T1    
) [Day] on Person.HomeID = [Day].HomeID
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          String = t4.RndString + LEFT(t3.TimeValue, 5)
        , t3.DayID
        , t3.HomeID
    FROM @TB1 t3
    JOIN @TB2 t4 ON t3.DayID = t4.DayType AND t3.TimeCode = t4.StringCode
) String ON [Day].DayID = String.DayID AND [Day].HomeID = String.HomeID 
GROUP BY Person.HomeID, [Day].DayID, String
FOR XML AUTO
```

**Output:**

```
<Person HomeID="1">
  <Day ID="1">
    <String>I get up at 07:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 07:30</String>
    <String>I go to office at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I come back from office at 17:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 19:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 21:30</String>
  </Day>
  <Day ID="2">
    <String>I get up at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 08:30</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 20:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 23:00</String>
  </Day>
</Person>
<Person HomeID="2">
  <Day ID="1">
    <String>I get up at 08:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 08:30</String>
    <String>I go to office at 09:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I come back from office at 18:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 20:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 22:00</String>
  </Day>
  <Day ID="2">
    <String>I get up at 09:00</String>
    <String>I have breakfast at 10:00</String>
    <String>I have lunch at 13:00</String>
    <String>I have dinner at 19:00</String>
    <String>I sleep at 22:30</String>
  </Day>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to create the XML from the data, right? If so, this will get you started

```
    public XDocument CreateXML(string[][] activities)
    {
        int HomeID = 1;
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(new XAttribute("HomeID", ""+HomeID++);

        foreach (string[] dayactivities in activities)
        {
            int ID=1;
            XElement day = new XElement("Day");
            day.Add(new XAttribute("ID", ""+ID++));
            doc.Add(day);

            foreach (string s in dayactivities)
                day.Add(new XElement("String", s));
        }

        return doc;
    }
```